# Как применить html/css к radio-кнопкам в rails-форме?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Я уже как только не пробовал - до применения к rails - кнопки работают нормально, но как только применяю в форме - становятся не кликабельными. Может есть в сети отдельное руководство по применению разных html/css эффектов к rails? Я искал, но не нашел ничего - где было бы все на конкретных примерах показано. Буду признателен за пример правильного наложения.

html:

```
<input type="radio" id="demo-priority-normal" name="demo-priority">
<label for="demo-priority-normal">3</label>

<input type="radio" id="demo-priority-high" name="demo-priority">
<label for="demo-priority-high">7</label>
```

rails:

```
<%= f.radio_button :three, '3_days', checked: true %>
<%= f.label :three, 'До 3 дней', value: '3_days' %>

<%= f.radio_button :seven, '7_days', checked: false %>
<%= f.label :seven, 'До 7 дней', value: '7_days' %>
```

---

**Обновление:**

Создал модель Expectation и ассоциациировал ее с Shipment через модель Shipment_Association. Затем добавил коллекцию радио-кнопок в форму. Радио-кнопки работают нормально, но результат тот же - при создании все значения остаются nil.

Shipment model:

```
belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friendship

  has_many :shipment_expectations
  has_many :expectations, through: :shipment_expectations
```

Expectation model:

```
has_many :shipment_expectations
  has_many :shipments, through: :shipment_expectations
```

ShipmentExpectation model:

```
belongs_to :shipment
  belongs_to :expectation
```

Форма:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :expectation_ids, Expectation.all, :id, :name %>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Просто. Откройте. [Документацию.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-radio_button)

...и найдите там используемый метод: в поисковом поле сверху слева наберите название метода (`radio_button`), узрите **два совпадения**, сравните их документацию, **не найдите различий** и посмотрите **любой из них**. Заметьте следующее:

> To force the radio button to be checked pass `checked: true` in the `options` hash. You may pass HTML options there as well.

То есть, в хэше опций можно непосредственно писать HTML-атрибуты, в том же хэше, где у вас указан ключ `:checked` (кстати, у него *по умолчанию* значение `false`, в таких случаях явно его указывать не нужно).

```
<%= f.radio_button :three, '3_days', checked: true, id: 'demo-priority-normal' %>
```

Ладно, в этом конкретном случае всё совсем просто, а если методов нашлось несколько и они разные? Тогда [вооружитесь ломиком (`pry`)](http://pryrepl.org/):

```
<%= form_for :whatever do |f| %>
  <% binding.pry %>
<% end %>
```

Это при рендере страницы должно вас выкинуть в интерактивную Ruby-сессию в точке, где лежит `binding.pry`, то есть, там доступна переменная `f`, которую можно пристально осмотреть. Скажем, можно посмотреть её класс:

```
> f.class
=> ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
```

...или даже открыть документацию:

```
> show-doc f.radio_button
...вывод довольно большой и совпадает с тем, что в документации
```

...или даже его исходный код! Если "недостаточно" :)

```
> show-source f.radio_button
```

---

<sub>Рекомендую для отладки добавить гемы `pry-rails`, `pry-byebug` и `pry-doc`: замену `rails console`, интеграцию с отладчиком и документацию к стандартной библиотеке.</sub>

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38382/discussion-between-d-side-and-lif3ar).